# How to add extra x-signature header with WebClient?

Tags: vb.net, webclient

This is my current code.

```
Public Shared Function downloadString1(url As String, post As String, signature As String) As String
    Dim wc = New CookieAwareWebClient

    Dim result = wc.UploadString(url, post)
    Return result
End Function
```

I need to insert post, url, and I should add x signature header I think

Now with `wc.UploadString`, I can do posts. But how do I add that extra x-signature header with WebClient?

This is the API instruction for yobit

https://yobit.net/en/api/

Comment: You're better-off using `HttpClient`.

Comment: You sure? So webclient can't do this. Right?